# MySQL select columns in multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building quiz type of software and I'm pretty much lost when building complex sql queries that select columns from different tables.

There are four tables that I need to get information from.

Tables structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIQaX.png

I have this sql query:

```
$questions = $this->db->get_results("
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT * from wp_ket_questions ".$where." ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$limit."
    ) t1
    JOIN wp_ket_answers t2 ON t1.id = t2.question_id
", ARRAY_A);
```

This query selects columns from **wp_ket_questions** table and answers from **wp_ket_answers** table. I also use JOIN to get answers that belong to certain question.

The question is: how do I incorporate **wp_ket_categories** and **wp_categories_questions** table in this SQL query so that I could get category name that is related to certain question?

**wp_ket_categories** table store all possible categories that I can append to question and **wp_categories_questions** table store cat_id and question_id columns, somehow I need to get category name from **wp_ket_categories** but I'm not sure how to properly join those tables.

I would be really grateful if someone could explain me what I need to change.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cqusing your logic, try this. You need to link each tables

```
SELECT * 
from wp_ket_questions q, wp_ket_answers a ,wp_ket_categories c ,wp_categories_questions cq
where 
q.id = a.question_id 
AND c.id = cq.cat_id 
AND a.question_id = cq.question_id
```